# React Native createContext() and useContext() returning null

Tags: react-native, react-context

I have tried looking at other posts with similar errors but I can't manage to find one that makes it work as expected.

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();
export default AuthContext;

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const authContext = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
          signIn: async (data) => {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
            dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', token: data.token, user: data});
          },
          signOut: async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');
            dispatch({type: 'SIGN_OUT'});
          }
        }),
        []
      );
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          authContext
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

Then in **App.js**

```
import { AuthContextProvider } from './AuthContext';

....

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
           <DetailsScreen />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
```

Then in **DetailsScreen.js**

```
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContext";

constructor(props) {
    const {context} = useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log("-----------------------------", context); // returns undefined
    super(props, context);
  }
```

The error this block of code is causing is:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

I am out of ideas as to what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context `AuthContext` that you created in `AuthContext.js` exports the context as `default`, but you import it as named-import, ie using `import {} from`. So the `useContext` hook takes as an argument a `null` instead of the actual context created by `React.createContext()`

Then be careful that `const {context} = useContext(AuthContext);` is also wrong as the hook will return the object `{authContext: {...}}` which means that you have to do `const {authContext} = useContext(AuthContext);`

In the Provider you can avoid passing `value={{authContext}}` and instead pass `value={authContext}` then you can just `const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't realize I was name importing. I've gone ahead and updated that, as well as passing value={authcontext} in the Provider. Nonetheless I'm still getting the same error about authContext being undefined. Not sure why.

Comment: You can export the `AuthContext` in `AuthContext.js` as default and then import it with `import AuthContext from './AuthContext` and then by saying `const {authContext} = useContext(AuthContext);` you supposed to take an object with the 2 functions defined.